# PHP: how to get numeric value of a string with multiple numbers?

Tags: php, string, type-conversion

Let's say in PHP I have a string-variable :   `"This takes between 5 and 7 days"`

I need to store some sensible information about the time it takes in an integer.

I'm satisfied if the result would be 5.

I tried stripping non-numeric characters, but end up with 57 then.

How can this be done in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match the first digit group using a regex:

```
$subject = 'This takes between 5 and 7 days';
if (preg_match('/\d+/', $subject, $matches)) {
    echo 'First number is: ' . $matches[0];
} else {
    echo 'No number found';
}
```

Using [`preg_match_all`](http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) you could match all digit groups (`5` and `7` in this example):

```
$subject = 'This takes between 5 and 7 days';
if (preg_match_all('/\d+/', $subject, $matches)) {
    echo 'Matches found:<br />';
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo 'No number found';
}
```

Comment: `/\d+/` is probably better, if numbers with more than one digit are possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quantify the numbers appropriately, I would suggest the following:

```
<?php
$subject = "This takes between 5 and 7 days";

$dayspattern = '/\d+(\.\d+)? ?days?/';
$hourspattern = '/\d+(\.\d+)? ?hours?/'

$hours = -1;

if (preg_match($dayspattern , $subject, $matches) > 0)
{
  preg_match($dayspattern, $matches[0], $days);
  $hours = $days * 24;
} elseif (preg_match($dayspattern , $subject, $matches) > 0) {
  preg_match($hourspattern, $matches[0], $hours);
  $hours = $hours;
}

?>
```

You would need to consider:

- what happens when no numbers are found, or numbers are given as text instead.
- what happens when someone says '1 day and 5 hours'

Hopefully this gives you enough information to do the rest yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to extract the price, ie €7.50 OR $50 etc
here is the regular expression comes to the solution for me.

```
 preg_match('/\d+\.?\d*/',$price_str,$matches); 
 echo $matches[0];
```

results 7.50 OR 50

Answer (score -1):

Seperate the subject into words by splitting the string into an array. Then, somehow I don't know, take the words out of the array. Maybe by looping through all children of the array inside a try-catch block, and try to change each element into an `int` type:

```
for($i=0;$i<$words->length;$i++){
    try{
        $tempNum = (int)$words[$i];
    }catch($ex){
        $words->remove($i);
    }
}
```

Or something like that. I don't know any of the array methods, but you get what I mean. Anyway, the `$words` array now only contains numbers.

Comment: First of all, this method would't work. You assume casting a string to an integer (by using `(int) $string`) would throw an exception if the string didn't contain digits. Furthermore an approach like this is not an elegant solution: you can use regexes to do this much better.